# smooth function support

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

Let $A$ be an open set in $R^n$. It is known that, we can construct a continuous function such that $\psi(x)>0$ for $x\in A$ and vanishes outside of $A$ (just use piece wise line segments). Can we restrict the conditions on $\psi$ further? that is, can we construct $\psi$ to be differentiable or even smooth?

Comment: what are line segments in $R^n$? and I suppose you mean any open set? Because you are claiming $A = \psi^{-1}(0,\infty)$, so if $A$ is not open and satisfies this then $\psi$ is necessarily not continuous?

Comment: Ahh yes yes open set, my bad.

Comment: Well you still need to replace line segments in $\mathbb R^n$. Anyway my google-fu is failing me but (1) iirc you can do it for continuous functions even in a metric space, I can't remember the theorem name. (2) As for differentiable or smooth functions yes, basically its [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function), (3)  its of course false for analytic functions by analytic continuation